# Windows bios fails to boot up, keeps resetting

Tags: windows-7

When I turn the computer on this error always happens wher jus after it starts up this screen pops up wher it says F1 to enter BIOS setup or F2 to start Windows Normally and if I press F2 it goes into Windows but freezez then I hav 2 turn the pc off, Problem is the BIOS + Date and Time keeps resetting itself somehow and it's not the battery because I put a new one in so when I manage 2 load default settings and get it working after some struggle and I shut down the pc the next day I switch the pc on and does the whole process again... What could this problem be and how can I fix it??? Thank you

Comment: The BIOS says “press F2 to load Windows Normally”? That’s a new one; I’ve **never** seen a BIOS mention a specific operating system, let alone *normally* (that is one of the options that Windows offers when it crashed the last time it tried to load). What system/motherboard is it? Is the BIOS corrupt or infected? o.O You may want to consider flashing a good/updated BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Check the battery is firmly seated and the correct way round. Check the the contacts, they may have been bent when you removed the old one. Check for dirt on the battery/contacts.